# Bootstrap correlation CI with increasing sample size

Tags: r, ggplot2, replication, correlation, confidence-interval

I would like to demonstrate how the width of a 95% confidence interval around a correlation changes with increasing sample size, from n = 10 to n=100 in increments of 5 samples per round. I would assume we can use a bootstrap function to do this and replicate each round 1000 times. How can this be done in R? 
See:
http://www.nicebread.de/at-what-sample-size-do-correlations-stabilize/

We can use the diamonds data:

```
data(diamonds)
x <- diamonds$price
y <- diamonds$carat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the chart and axis titles yourself, but this code does what I think you're looking for using ggplot2 and the 'psychometric' package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(psychometric)

corSamp <- function(x) {
# return the correlation between price and carat on diamonds for a given sample size
  index <- sample(1:nrow(diamonds), x)
  carat <- diamonds$carat[index]
  price <- diamonds$price[index]
  return(cor(carat, price))
}

cors <- sapply(seq(5,100,5), corSamp)
lower <- sapply(1:20, function(i) return(CIr(r = cors[i], n = seq(5,100,5)[i], level = 0.95)[1]))
upper <- sapply(1:20, function(i) return(CIr(r = cors[i], n = seq(5,100,5)[i], level = 0.95)[2]))

myData <- data.frame(cbind(cors, lower, upper, seq(5,100,5)))

myPlot <- ggplot(myData, aes(x = V4, y = cors)) + geom_line() + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: Sample size vs. correlation]

Here V4 is the sample size.

Comment: Very nice! Is it possible to enhance this so for each sample size (5 through 100) we replicate the draw 1000 times and in similar fashion report the mean of the correlation for each sample size, plus the corresponding upper and lower CI ? [See josilber's answer below]

Comment: So you're not looking for the mathematically determined confidence interval for a correlation with a given sample size, you actually want to bootstrap 1000 sets for each sample size and get the CI for the distributions of correlations? You should be able to do that by combining our answers. Use his answer to generate your samples, and then make the upper and lower bounds of the geom_ribbon the upper and lower CI values.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your sample sizes with `sapply`, and for each sample size draw 1000 random samples of the appropriate size, reporting the average width of the confidence interval:

```
set.seed(144)
ci.widths <- sapply(seq(10, 100, 5), function(x) mean(replicate(1000, {
  r <- sample(nrow(diamonds), x, replace=TRUE)
  diff(cor.test(diamonds$price[r], diamonds$carat[r])$conf.int)
})))
plot(seq(10, 100, 5), ci.widths, xlab="Sample size", ylab="CI width")
```

[image]